# What statistical test to use (dental thesis)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kruskal-wallis-test

I am a fourth year dental student from Belgium and have to chose an appropriate statistical test for my thesis. I have to compare tongue posture and tongue position between 3 groups, but can't seem to get the right test. Tongue posture and tongue position are qualitative variables I suppose, so in my first opinion I would chose for a Kruskall-Wallis test.

So, I have 3 groups, first of all data (tongue posture and tongue function) is collected before starting any treatment. Than I will have 3 groups with different treatment modalities and at the end I will again compare tongue posture and tongue function between the 3 groups. 3) My promoter said tongue posture will be evaluated in a qualitative analysis (4 groups: normal, low, low, inconclusive). Tongue function will be evaluated as a quantitative analysis.